# CSS3 image slider with continuous slide animation

Tags: css, slider

I was trying to create a pure css3 image slider with infinite continuous slide animation. I was able to do the animation using CSS3 but a small issue facing at the end of last slide. After last slide it gets suddenly to the first slide without css3 smooth transform effect. Any simple possible way to fix this ?
Here is the code

```
#slideshow{
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 5px solid #fff;}
#slideshow img{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide{
0%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
33%{ transform:translateX(-200px) }
66%{ transform:translateX(-400px) }
100%{ transform:translateX(-600px) }
}

<div id="slideshow"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/24mia39.jpg"></div>
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vzxfm7b1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't animation after last side because your animation is finish. Maybe add a transform effect like :

```
@keyframes slide{
   0%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
   25%{ transform:translateX(-200px) }
   50%{ transform:translateX(-400px) }
   75%{ transform:translateX(-600px) }
   100%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
}
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vzxfm7b1/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This I have already tried. Actually I need continuous loop animation. Now currently after last slide its moving all the way back to first slide, which is not I'm looking for.